# Python concatenate string with string variable having escape characters

Tags: python-3.x, scripting

I had a command in python script as below:

```
start_command = [
        "load=" + location + "/lib/abc " + "conf=myconf " +
        location + "/bin/mysqld "
        "--defaults-file=" + location + "/var/myfile.cnf " 
        ]
```

I want to push the second part of the code as a variable(connect_str) & concatenate in start command. but it's not working . Is this because of escape character?

```
 connect_str="conf=myconf " +
        location + "/bin/mysqld "
        "--defaults-file=" + location + "/var/myfile.cnf "
 start_command = [
        "load=" + location + "/lib/abc " + connect_str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using \ to scape \n

```
connect_str = "conf=myconf " + location + \
    " /bin/mysqld " "--defaults-file=" + location + \
    " /var/myfile.cnf "
```

Answer (score 1):

if u want concatenate str its should be str , i see a list in your code, and no escape character is this \ in your there are /. I recommend you to use format is much better like this

```
connect_str="conf=myconf {} /bin/mysqld --defaults-file={} /var/myfile.cnf ".format(location,location)
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in declaring the string variable which i changed & made it work. It was actually annotation issue due to putting in multiple lines.

```
connect_str="conf=myconf " + location + "/bin/mysqld " "--defaults-file=" + location + "/var/myfile.cnf "
 start_command = [
        "load=" + location + "/lib/abc " + connect_str
          ]
```

Is there any better way to resolve the issue rather than putting it in single line?